# Is there a way to detect the PC Flash Signal or exact moment the shutter opens via the canon EDSK?

Tags: usb, edsdk, canon-sdk

I currently have a device that drives the camera via bulb mode.  It has one cable connected to the bulb connector, and the other to the PC flash connector.  The PC flash signal is only triggered as soon as the shutter is open.  There is up to 100 ms of variable latency between triggering the shutter and it actually opening.  So if I want to expose for exactly 50 ms, I trigger bulb, wait for PC flash signal, then wait 50 ms, then stop triggering bulb.  I now have a USB version of this device that uses the EDSDK, the only problem is that I can't find any sort of EDSDK event that is the equivalent of the PC flash signal.  Is there any EDSDK event that signals the exact moment that the shutter opens?

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest is looking at the image time after collect. Even if there were, it would be far from precise due to latency of the event getting back to the host computer via USB, then into the application. To maintain accuracy on that level, you'll have to control the camera through its available hardware interfaces - the PC flash signal and the remote trigger. There may also be issues with trying to do fast exposures and using the PC port, as these are usually done with slow exposures. One canon camera manual, for instance, says the PC port only works at 1/250s and slower.